# Control external device using Java Web Servlet -> Pi -> Arduino -> Device

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, web-server, home-automation

I'm new to the world of Arduino & PI, so far it's been a fantastic experience but I'm now looking to build something a bit more practical.

My plan is for the PI to host a JSP Servlet website.  I'd like to go to a certain page of this site: 'powerCycleDevice' for example where it would pass a parameter in '?=on' or something similar.  This would then be picked up by the Arduino which in turn would then power said device.

It's also be nice to just use it as a monitoring station.  If I have several Arduinos hooked up (and I plan to - think Wallace & Gromit :)) then it'd be nice to view the statistics of each of the sensors.

My problem is not knowing if a: it's possible (I'm certain it is) and b: where to start.

If anyone can lend any advice, hints or tips on where to get started it would be fantastic.  A noob guide or tutorial would be great as I'd then use the info and expand upon it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Ardulink. It's a java open source project of mine. It can control an Arduino boad. So you have just to write a servlet that call my library. That's it.

See this post to understand how install ardulink in a PI: http://www.ardulink.org/how-to-install-arduino-pc-link-on-raspberry-pi/

You can read a sample code that sends some messages to Arduino you can read this post:
http://www.ardulink.org/how-to-blink-a-led/

The most important statement is **Link link = Link.getDefaultInstance();**

**Link** is the Ardulink class you need to send (and receive) messages.

Comment: That's fantastic, thank you. I'll have a look as soon as I'm able to